# How to check the course material for Sitecore 10 Certification with New Sitecore Learning Portal

Tags: training-certification

When I go to the below link on the `Sitecore` website, it shows the links to all the `Sitecore certifications`.

https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started/training

[image]

But when I click on `Sitecore 10 .NET Developer` link, it redirects me to a page that requires a login.

[image]

My question is, do we need to login to see the content of the course before purchasing? If someone doesn't have login credentials then how they can see the course material?

Also previously I looked into this course and it comes up with the `Sitecore 10 course material` but now this is also not working.

https://learning.sitecore.com/pathway/sitecore-developer-bundle

Can someone suggest, if `Sitecore` has new links for `Sitecore 10 course` material?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created a support ticket with Sitecore and got some context on this.

Now the course is available on Sitecore learning and here is the link.

https://shop.learning.sitecore.com/products/bb21d39f-8a39-d1

And this course will also give you an attempt of Sitecore 10 certification. Here are the details.

> Development with Sitecore 9 eLearning Collection Development with
> Sitecore 10 eLearning Collection System Administration with Sitecore
> 10 eLearning Collection 1 voucher to take the Sitecore 10 .NET
> Developer Certification Exam Sitecore 10 .NET Developer Certification
> Exam Study Guide Note: The content and exam apply to developing for
> both Sitecore Experience Manager (XM) and Sitecore Experience Platform
> (XP)

You need to log in with your Sitecore credentials. If you don't have then you need to create an account.

Answer (score 3):

This link https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started/training is still pointing to old URLs and will redirect you to the login page of the new Sitecore learning portal. The Sitecore team needs to update the content here, hoping they will do it soon.

Now with regards to your other questions -

**Do we need to log in to see the content of the course before purchasing?**- Yes, Sitecore's new learning portal's default page is the login page, so you need to log in first before doing anything on this portal. you can click any of the login types which best fit you. Sitecore's login uses OKTA so once you will do successful login you will be able to see the learning home page.

[image]

**If someone doesn't have login credentials then how they can see the course material?** - If someone is not having logins he/she needs to create an account on https://www.sitecore.com/account/signup it asks for a business email but will work for your Gmail or other email ids as well. once signup will be complete you will receive an email to set up your login password

**Alternative of https://learning.sitecore.com/pathway/sitecore-developer-bundle** - Once you will log in to the learning portal, on the home page you can browse for the learning catalog, which will give you a complete list of available products. You will be able to see the Sitecore bundle there. once you will log in you can run this URL as well - https://shop.learning.sitecore.com/products/bb21d39f-8a39-d1 (but this will not work properly if you are not logged in, it will redirect you to a login page which will not work as shop.learning website is using token-based authorization.

[image]

But this is a new portal and things are still going on you will not get everything that was in the old learning portal.